# How to display styled text in a JXEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I'm displaying some text in a JTextPane, with some syntax highlighting using an implementation of DefaultStyledDocument. This works.
Now I wanted to add a search (ctrl-F) functionality, and tried using a JXEditorPane from swingx instead of the JTextPane.
I'm doing:

```
p = new JXEditorPane();
p.setEditable(false);
p.setDocument(new MyStyledDocument());
p.getDocument().addDocumentListener( ... some callbacks ... );
```

My callbacks are called as expected. However, the text does not appear to be styled. Is this feasible ? (I noticed that only the doc in JTextPane talks about StyledDocument, the setDocument() from JTextComponent just talks about Document).

[edit] I reduced the code down to (sorry for the length, it's the best I could do):

MyStyledDocument.java:

```
package com.mydemo;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class MyStyledDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument {
    private Style _style;

    public MyStyledDocument() {
        _style = addStyle("bluuuue", null);
        StyleConstants.setBold(_style, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(_style, new Color(0, 250, 255));
    }

    public synchronized void applyStyle() {
        System.out.println("applyStyle");
        setCharacterAttributes(0, getLength(), _style, true);
    }
}
```

Gui.java:

```
package com.mydemo;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXEditorPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Gui() {
        super();
        setSize(100, 100);

        JEditorPane pane = new JTextPane();  // replace by new JXEditorPane() here
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.setDocument(new MyStyledDocument());

        pane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { applyStyleInNextTick(e); }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { applyStyleInNextTick(e); }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { /* Do NOT restyle here, as this gets triggered by styling */ }
            private void applyStyleInNextTick(final DocumentEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
                        ((MyStyledDocument) e.getDocument()).applyStyle();
                    }});
            }
        });
        pane.setText("FooBar");
        this.setContentPane(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

By default, the text is colored in blue. Switching to using a JXEditorPane (1 statement change) gives the same thing with the text not colored.

Comment: `Is this feasible ?` - is what feasible? You stated that you are using "syntax highlighting", so styled text is feasible. `My callbacks are called as expected. However, the text does not appear to be styled` - Make sure the code is wrapped in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), otherwise you will not be able to modify the StyledDocument from within the DocumentListener. Why are you use JXEditorPane? If the syntax highliting is done in the Document you should be able to use a normal JTextPane. Post a `SSCCE` if you need more help.

Comment: Is it wrapped in a invokeLater. Styling is working with a plain JTextPane.I'm trying to combine styling and the facilities (search) offered by JXEditorPane.

Comment: How does the "MyStyledDocument" work? Does it use attributes for the syntax highlighting, or does it use HTML. A JEditorPane only works with HTML so if the custom Document uses attributes then there may be a problem (don't know for sure).

Comment: It defines javax.swing.text.Style's, scans the text, and calls setCharacterAttributes with index ranges and styles. The Styles only have foreground color and/or bold attributes set.